# Remove spaces between greater than signs

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like this:

```
foo > bar > foo bar > foo > test > test this
```

I would like to take any strings within the greater than signs and convert them into single words with no space between them but preserve all other spaces like this:

```
foo > bar > foobar > foo > test > testthis
```

I've tried using gsub to remove whitespace `gsub(" ", "", x, fixed = TRUE)`, but I am not sure how to do this only within the greater than signs while preserving the spaces next to the greater than signs

Comment: Try `gsub("(?<=\\w)\\s(?=\\w|\\$)", "", str1, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be a PCRE `SKIP/FAIL` by matching zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by `>` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`).  At the `(*SKIP)`, it no longer goes back to the right of the match nor retry it.  The `(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to FAIL until the left of (*SKIP) while it matches the space characters (`|\\s+`) right of the (`(*FAIL)`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\s*\\>\\s*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s+", "", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "foo > bar > foobar > foo > test > testthis"
```

---

Or another option is to match space between two word characters.  Here the spaces are matched between a positive regex lookbehind word character (`(?<=\\w)`) and a positive lookahead word character or at the end of the string (`(?=\\w|\\$)`)

```
gsub("(?<=\\w)\\s(?=\\w|\\$)", "", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "foo > bar > foobar > foo > test > testthis"
```

---

Or without using regex lookarounds, we can capture the word

```
gsub("(\\w)\\s(\\w)", "\\1\\2", str1)
#[1] "foo > bar > foobar > foo > test > testthis"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "foo > bar > foo bar > foo > test > test this"
```

Comment: another option: `gsub('(?<!>) (?!>)', '', str1, perl = T)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve what you want with a pattern that will match and *capture* `>` enclosed with whitespaces (using `(\s*>\s*)`) and matching without capturing all other 1+ whitespace chunks (`\s+`) - all you need to make the pattern work is to replace with a backreference to Group 1 value (`\1`):

```
gsub("(\\s*>\\s*)|\\s+", "\\1", x)
```

Or, to account for Unicode strings,

```
gsub("(*UCP)(\\s*>\\s*)|\\s+", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcmuwA/1).

**Details**

- `(\s*>\s*)` - Capturing group 1: 0+ whitespaces, `>`, 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars.

See [R demo online](https://ideone.com/I6CK8P):

```
x <- "foo > bar > foo bar > foo > test > test this"
gsub("(\\s*>\\s*)|\\s+", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "foo > bar > foobar > foo > test > testthis"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an (arguably) more tractable solution for the non-regex-expert:

```
# Split into parts
str2 <- unlist(strsplit(str1, ">"))
str2
[1] "foo "       " bar "      " foo bar "  " foo "      " test "     " test this"

# Eliminate all spaces
str3 <- gsub(" ", "", str2)
str3
[1] "foo"      "bar"      "foobar"   "foo"      "test"     "testthis"

# And now paste again together 
str_final <- paste(str3, collapse = " > ")
str_final
[1] "foo > bar > foobar > foo > test > testthis"
```